# RNGCryptoServiceProvider for 3DES and AES keys

Tags: .net, cryptography

I saw some people using `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` for generating random keys for `AES`, `3DES` and `DES`. I'm also aware of the difference between `AES` and `3DES` keys (https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/24210/128-bit-3des-key-and-aes-key-whats-the-difference). My question: is it okay to use this `RNG` to generate keys for these algorithms or should I use `TripleDES.GenerateKey()` and `AES.GenerateKey()`? Since all bits matter to the result for `AES`, I wouldn't really see a problem using this `RNG`, but I'm not sure about `3DES`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` makes use of the random number generator of the operating system. This is exactly the same random number generator that the `GenerateKey` methods will use. So in effect, usually the difference will be minimal.

In general you should use `GenerateKey`:

- The main reason is that it is more readable and therefore more maintainable.
- The bytes returned by the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` won't have DES parity. Generally implementations don't care if the DES keys have correct parity and for DES calculations they are fully ignored. However, it may be that some DES libraries will require DES parity, so if you distribute them you may get in trouble.
- Using `GenerateKey` would also allow a hardware CSP to be used, where the keys can stay in hardware. You could possibly import the key, but then the key would have been in memory first; not all hardware devices allow easy import of keys, and if they do they are considered less trustworthy. A hardware device may also offer a more secure random number generator.

So unless you have a compelling reason to use the RNG (for instance, you need to export the keys directly afterwards) I would certainly try and use the designated `GenerateKey` functions.

If they were useless they would not exist, right?